# "the best singer of those ones who sang" / "the best singer of those who sang" / "the best of the singers who sang"

Tags: sentence-usage

> He was **the best singer of those ones** who sang in the concert yesterday.
>
> He was **the best singer of those** who sang in the concert yesterday.
>
> He was **the best of the singers** who sang in the concert yesterday.

Do all sentences sound good? I tried to do the research in Google Books. For example, I saw that phrases "of those who" & "of those ones who" are used in English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ask yourself this: does it make sense to pluralize the number "one" here? Nope. And, I can confirm, "those ones" certainly doesn't sound good.

Your other two options are equally valid.

Comment: Are there rules when it make sense to use "one/ones" and when it doesn't make sense to use it?

Comment: Saying "those ones" as you have in your first example isn't necessarily wrong, but it doesn't sound proper. It doesn't sound good because in a vast majority of situations where it could be used, it's easier to simply not use it. Thus, because that is what people end up saying a majority of the time, that's what sounds better. E.g., “I prefer those ones on the left.” vs “I prefer those on the left.”

Comment: The rule would then be to not use "ones" unless it makes sense on its own. E.g., "They came in packages of ones and twos."